# Refresh View Whilst Function Still Executes

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to play the simplest "animation", by making a TextView say "foo", wait a second, then say "bar".
The problem is that instead of seeing the label nicely shifting, it freezes for the whole second and then just says the last requested text.

```
val label = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

button.setOnClickListener {
    label.text = "foo"
    // some "label.update()" has to be called here
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    label.text = "bar"
}
```

In C# I would solve this by adding "this.update()" before sleeping; however, I couldn't find any similar function in Android libraries.

How would you force a view to refresh its looks before the function finishes?

Comment: You can enclose this inside the Handler with Delay

>
Handler().postDelayed({
                        // You UI Changes Here

                    }, 1000)

Comment: See this https://medium.com/@elye.project/switching-text-with-animation-f129eef83786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's pausing the main thread for 1000ms.

You can avoid that by replacing these two lines:

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
label.text = "bar"
```

... with this:

```
Handler().postDelayed( { label.text = "bar" }, 1000)
```

There are other ways but this is simplest, I think.

Comment: Thank you, IT WORKS, I'll use that :]
Although it doesn't address the title question "Refresh View Whilst Function Still Executes" which I'm still curious about. 
maybe the answer would be to continue that execution in a different thread